# How can I place images dynamically in Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a header component in Figma and im trying to add the images so they appear the same as the figma illustration, however im not sure how to navigate the images properly so they can stay mobile responsive.

This is the desired outcome!

[image: This is the desired outcome]

This is my progress :)
[image]

Below is the code for the header using react!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from '../utils/Modal';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import HeroImage from '../images/hero-image.png';
import image1 from '../images/illustration1.png'
import image2 from '../images/illustration2.png'

function HeroHome() {

  const [videoModalOpen, setVideoModalOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <section className="relative bg-blitblue-100">

<div className="md:absolute left-3/4 transform -translate-x-3/4 bottom-30 pointer-events-none" aria-hidden="true">
<img src={image1} /> 
      </div>

      <div className="md:absolute right-20 transform -translate-x-3/4 bottom-30 pointer-events-none" aria-hidden="true">
<img src={image2} /> 
      </div>

      <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 ">

        {/* Hero content */}
        <div className="pt-32 pb-12 md:pt-40 md:pb-20">

          {/* Section header */}
          <div className="text-center pb-12 md:pb-16">
            <h1 className="text-6xl md:text-6xl font-extrabold leading-tighter tracking-tighter mb-4" data-aos="zoom-y-out"><span className="bg-clip-text text-transparent bg-blitblue-200">BlitCore</span></h1>
            <div className="max-w-3xl mx-auto">
              <p className="text-xl text-blittext-100 mb-8" data-aos="zoom-y-out" data-aos-delay="150">We are an OutSourcing Company that Specialize in Building and Maintaing Solutions</p>
              <div className="max-w-xs mx-auto sm:max-w-none sm:flex sm:justify-center" data-aos="zoom-y-out" data-aos-delay="300">
                {/* <div>
                  <a className="btn text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 w-full mb-4 sm:w-auto sm:mb-0" href="#0">Start free trial</a>
                </div> */}
                <div>
                  <Link className="btn text-white bg-blitblue-200 hover:bg-gray-800 w-full sm:w-auto sm:ml-4" to="contact">Lets Begin</Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default HeroHome;
```

Comment: You can achieve same thing just by using flex or grid instead of transform and achieving responsive design with css transform is painful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [negative value](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left#using-negative-values) of top/right/bottom/left to adjust the position instead of adding `translate`. Alternatively, you can also use calc() to position the image if you enable [JIT](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-to-the-jit-engine) mode.

Example:

Image 1

```
class="md:absolute md:left-[calc(100%+2rem)] md:top-2"
```

Image 2

```
class="md:absolute md:right-[calc(100%+2rem)] md:top-5"
```

Comment: The images just disappear once i add these lines, i used jit in my module exports, but not sure if the issue is from jit